# hunspell not working

Tags: hunspell

I install the hunspell in Ubuntu 18.04 today, I'm trying to use it but it seems to not work. Maybe the problem is me xD.

At /usr/share/hunspell I have en_US.aff and en_US.dic but the OpenOffice don't detect any dictionary and I can't select any dictionary in spellright at vscode too.